# Scenekit rotate node to face tapped point

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm using the default scenekit game project to try and implement some tap controls to fly the ship around, the default one that comes with that project. What i'm trying to figure out, is how to rotate my ship's nose to face the point that is tapped on screen. I have been following any and all examples of this i've seen and have come up with this:

```
let point:CGPoint = sender.location(in: sender.view)
let deltaY:Float = Float(point.y) - ship.position.y
let deltaX:Float = Float(point.x) - ship.position.x
let degreesToRadians = Float.pi / 180
let angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX) + (90 * degreesToRadians)
ship.rotation = SCNVector4(0,1,0,angle)
```

A few things to note:

- I'm not changing the `rotation` or `position` of the ship on load, both properties print with `0` for each point.
- When i load the project, the ship points down. It's my understanding that you need to offset your calculation of `angle` to be at 0 degrees, so thats why i do `+ (90 * degreesToRadians)` in my `angle` calculation.

What happens when I tap my finger around the ship in a circle is the ship rotates in a 90degree arc from 0deg - 90deg. Just incase that isn't clear (or correct), it's moving between east and north no matter where i am tapping on the screen.

one last thing to note. My camera is locked to an overhead view, so i only want to be rotating the Y axis, here is a quick screenshot of the orientation and first load position:
[image: first load position]

If you have any tips, ideas or knowledge to send my way that would be great. This problem has me stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getting close, theres just a couple conversion steps your missing.

First convert the location of the tap in the views coordinates, this is the same as your code, just different names.

```
let viewPoint = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
```

Since the view is 2D but the SCNScene is 3D, you need to convert into scene coordinates using [`scnView.unprojectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522631-unprojectpoint).

```
let camera = cameraNode.camera
let distance = camera.zFar - camera.zNear / cameraNode.position.y
let scenePoint = scnView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(viewPoint.x, viewPoint.y, CGFloat(distance)))
```

Then calculate the angle. The important thing in your case is that you're looking straight down so the axises you want to work with are X and Z. Also, positive X is on the right but positive Z is pointing down which needs to be taken into account.

```
let deltaZ = scenePoint.z - ship.position.z
let deltaX = scenePoint.x - ship.position.x
let angle = atan2(deltaZ, deltaX) - .pi / 2
ship.rotation = SCNVector4(0, -1, 0, angle)
```

And that should do it. Also not that if you camera was rotated by any amount that isn't a multiple of 90 degrees, the 2D -> 3D conversion and angle calculation will be much more complicated since it isn't as simple as treating one axis as another one.

---

Edit - Rotation across 0/360 deg boundary

You'll need to check wether rotating clockwise or counter clockwise will require more movement and update the angle.

```
if abs(angle - .pi * 2 - ship.rotation.w) < abs(angle - ship.rotation.w) {
    angle -= .pi * 2
}
```

Also, I think Quaternions may handle this automatically but I'm not familiar enough with them to post a solution.

Comment: This works perfectly, THANK YOU. Just a couple of optional and number type fixes and its all good. One small issue is when i animate it with `SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle: rotationVector, duration: 0.5)` the node won't cross over the 360deg / 0deg border, it animates all the way back around. Which definitely makes sence... going from 360 to 0, Have you ever had to deal with something like this?

Comment: wow awesome, thank you man. I've looked into Quaternions before but i'm just getting into all this stuff and they confused me lol, so i'll stick with this for now. Again, you've really helped me understand this stuff and i really appreciate it!